# Google App Engine (Python) app.yaml urlhandler doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, handlers, app.yaml

I'm trying google app engine with python27.

```
    handlers:
    - url: /favicon\.ico
      static_files: favicon.ico
      upload: favicon\.ico

    - url: /hello
      script: helloworld.app

    - url: /.*
      script: main.app
```

helloworld.py and main.app have the same code from the offical document with little difference (response string).

```
import webapp2
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!!!')
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

My result:
1. "~", the response comes from "main.app". 
2. "~/favicon.ico", the response comes from "favicon.ico".
3. "~/hello", the response is "404".
4. "~/something", the response is "404".

Sorry, to post this question, "~" for `"http://localhost:8080"`.

Why 3 and 4 cannot be handled? Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `('/', MainHandler)` to `(r'/.*', MainHandler)` (the `r` just indicates it is a raw string). The problem is that you don't currently have any handlers for anything other than your root `/`, so requests with other parameters (such as `http://localhost:8080/hello`) have no matching handler and therefore it is unknown how to handle it. Changing the handler to `/.*` means that all requests (regardless of what comes after the root) should be routed to your `MainHandler`.

As for the `app.yaml` handlers and the handlers in your `*.py` file, think of the `app.yaml` as the high-level director. It gets a request and simply determines where to send it (am I getting a request for a static Javascript file? CSS? Picture? Or is this a request that should serve a page, etc.?). In the case such as yours above, you want it to serve a particular page when hitting any URL that is not `/favicon` (so `/.*`), so what it does is takes any request to `/.*` and routes it to `main.app`, which is in your `main.py` file (I'm ignoring `helloworld.app` for now, mainly because in your situation you don't necessarily need it).

It is then that the more granular handling happens - `main.app` receives the original request, and then it looks for a specific handler to execute the code. When we change your handlers to `r'/.*'`, it matches anything that comes in (so `/`, `/hello`, `/helloworld`, etc.), and it executes the corresponding class `MainHandler`, in this case).

Comment: Thanks so much, the problem has been solved. I will read something for more, finding out the differences between the two handlers in app.yaml and *.py.

Comment: @Babeler No problem, happy it helped :) Check out http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html, which is webapp2's documentation on URL routing (you're using the webapp2 framework). I added a bit more detail to the answer that will hopefully be useful. Good luck with everything.